# Java program that opens webpage on browser then plays video on Computer

Tags: java, video, browser

I am wondering if there's a way to create a program that opens a browser on a computer, goes to a website URL, then plays a streaming video on the website and makes it fullscreen. I'm creating a listing of web streams and want to allow some friends to click on a link which opens the browser, makes the video on browser full screen, then plays the video on the browser. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
String URL = "http://www.jagobd.com/atnnews";
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(new URI(URL));
```

Essentially, it's a simple program that just plays the video on a streaming website with just one click of a button. I'm not looking to download the video or anything, just a quick access to certain live streams on a single click.

Comment: A regular web link will open the default browser and start streaming the video, so I am guessing the functionality you are missing and want is for it to be full screen?

Comment: Yes, but in some streaming websites the video does not start streaming until the user clicks the video which I think can be solved with selenium library, but making the video full screen is the biggest issue  and I'm not sure how to do this